# Djangorestframework Modelresource add a field from an foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an api in django-rest framework that now returns this json data:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "foreignobject": {
            "id": 3
        },
        "otherfields": "somevalue"
    }
]
```

But I want it to return something like this (flatten the foreigneky to its ID only):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "foreignobject_id":3,
        "otherfields": "somevalue"
    }
]
```

Doing this in the model Resource, now I Have (simplified):

```
class ForeignKeyInDataResource(ModelResource):
    model = TheOtherModel
    fields = ('id',)


class SomeModelResource(ModelResource):
    model = SomeModel
    fields = ( 'id',('foreignobject','ForeignKeyInDataResource'),'otherfields',)
```

I tried already something like:

```
class SomeModelResource(ModelResource):
    model = SomeModel
    fields = ( 'id','foreignobject__id','otherfields',)
```

but that did not work

for the complete story, this how the view returns the data, list is a result of a query over the SomeModel:

```
data = Serializer(depth=2 ).serialize(list)
return Response(status.HTTP_200_OK, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another option: (by reading the ModelResource documentation...)
In the Modelresource you can define a function(self,instance), which can return the id.

in the fields you can add this function!

so, this works:

```
class SomeModelResource(ModelResource):
    model = SomeModel
    fields = ( 'id','foreignobject_id','otherfields',)

    def foreignobject_id(self, instance):
        return instance['foreignobject']['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really in a position to support REST framework 0.x anymore, but if you decide to upgrade to 2.0 this is trivial - simply declare the field on the serializer like so: `foreignobject = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'll keep that in mind, updating is not an option right now.

Comment: As you saw in another question you answered... working on the migration. Very nice work done in the path to the newest version of the rest framework!